# PHP-AJAX, load more data on scroll: what if there's more data available but no need for scrolling?

Tags: php, ajax, infinite-scroll

I've got a working load more data on scrolling using PHP and Jquery.
It fetches 10 rows of data and displays them in a scrollable div container, which is 90% of the viewport in height.
On scrolling the next set of 10 rows is loaded.

My question: what if the available height of the scrollable div container is greater than the height required by the first 10 rows of data?
In this case there'll be no need for scrolling (in fact there isn't even a scrollbar present) and no more data, however available, can be loaded.
How would you tackle this problem?
Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Usually you scroll the view to focus on the new, added entries in your list. Which means if there is no need to scroll, then no scroll will be performed. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand, But what if the initial set of records loaded require less space (in height) than the height of the container? In that case no further data will be loaded.

Comment: Two options: First you can think about what you actually define as "the initial set of records". This does not have to be a fixed number but can be the result of a computation based on the relation of available space and height consumption per entry. And second, easier, you can simply add a check each time you added records to check if the resulting set actually fills the available space or not. Third you could check if the scroll position has changed, but that would only be a very indirect approach ...

Comment: And fourth you can simply initially load a much bigger set of records. It typically hardly makes a difference in performance anyway, since aspects like network or request latency usually are the limiting factors here. Use a _big_ initial set. And fifth, probably the easiest, you can simply check the scroll position after the initial load. If it is still unchange you fetch the next batch. Until the scroll position has in fact changed.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your extensive answer. This really puts me in the right direction.